# When the use of reflection is good practice?

Tags: java, reflection

I have various methods to validate an object. For now i run the validation like this:

```
boolean error = false;
if(!methodOneValidade(myObject)) error = true;
if(!methodTwoValidade(myObject)) error = true;
if(!methodTreeValidade(myObject)) error = true;
.
.
.
if(!method23Validade(myObject)) error = true;
return error;
```

Instead, if i annotate the methods with an specific annotation (@MyRule e.g.) and execute them using reflection, is it a good practice?
For me will be smart and practical, but is it acceptable way use of reflection in java?

Example 1 - Without reflection:

```
public class ClientRules {
    private Client client;

    public ClienteNegocio(Cliente cliente) {
        this.client = cliente;
    }

    public boolean validateAge() {
        return client.getIdade()>=18;
    }

    public boolean validateInicialInput() {
        return client.getAporteInicial() > 999.99;
    }

    public boolean validateAccountBalance() {
        MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();
        List<SomeObject> list = db.getClientHistory(client);
        double finalValue = 0;

        if(list.size()>=100) {
            double sum = 0;
            for(SomeObject someObject: list){
                sum = sum + someObject.value();
            }
            finalValue = sum/list.size();
            return finalValue>=5.5;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        return validateEmail() && validateAge() && validateAccountBalance() && validateInicialInput();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientRules clientRules = new ClientRules(client);
        if(clientRules.validate())
            System.out.println("Success!");
        else
            System.out.println("Fail!");
    }
}
```

Example 2 - With reflection

```
public class ClientRules {
    private Client client;

    public ClienteNegocio(Cliente cliente) {
        this.client = cliente;
    }

    @Rule
    public boolean validateAge() {
        return client.getIdade()>=18;
    }

    @Rule
    public boolean validateInicialInput() {
        return client.getAporteInicial() > 999.99;
    }

    @Rule
    public boolean validateAccountBalance() {
        MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase();
        List<SomeObject> list = db.getClientHistory(client);
        double finalValue = 0;
        if(list.size()>=100) {
            double sum = 0;
            for(SomeObject someObject: list){
                sum = sum + someObject.value();
            }
            finalValue = sum/list.size();
            return finalValue>=5.5;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClientRules clientRules = new ClientRules(client);
        for (Method method : clientRules.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
            if (method.isAnnotationPresent(Rule.class)) {
                try {
                    boolean result = (boolean)method.invoke(clientRules);
                    if (!result) {
                        System.out.println("Fail!");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("...");
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that acceptable or not is a matter of opinion

Comment: I'm not sure I would use reflection in this situation. I believe there could be a way to improve your structure and architecture where you eliminate this smelly code without the need of the reflection API. You brought up a good point, though.

Comment: There is a already a library which done the validation using annotation. Its a java standard. Please check [BeanValidation](http://beanvalidation.org). Also please take exception in to consideration. It will be way more elegant to throw exceptions instead returning boolean.

Comment: @bhdrkn `It will be way more elegant to throw exceptions instead returning boolean.`... since when? Exceptions are almost never better than simply returning specific values (be they `null`, `false`, or other "falsy" values).

Comment: Look here http://beanvalidation.org/1.1/spec/ , yes annotation is a good idea. However flags are not :)

Comment: @Jashaszun I wouldn't go as far as saying they're "almost never better", but they should be generally only be thrown under unrecoverable or unexpected circumstances.

Comment: This may be appropriate on [codereview.se], but I believe you'll need to modify the question quite a bit first - check out [their help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for guidance on how to proceed and whether it is actually appropriate ("is using reflection here good practice" probably isn't on topic there, but asking them to review your code might give you the answer you're looking for).

Comment: @Dukeling It indeed needs a lot of editing to be on-topic on CR, as this is just example code which is off-topic on CR. Asking for "is this usage of reflection good practice?" is perfectly alright, as long as that usage of reflection has been implemented, and real code is shown.